# Формы глаголов в русском языке

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть такие глаголы, как "раздражать", "соблюдать", но я вот думаю - существуют ли у них 1-ое лицо будущего времени? "Раздражу", "Соблюду", по моему мнению, их не бывает в нашем русском языке. Я прав? Если да, то как можно сказать по-другому?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует. **Буду соблюдать** и **буду раздражать**.

А в целом вопрос, конечно, некорректный. Будущее время у глаголов *раздражать* и *соблюдать*, как и у всех глаголов несовершенного вида, имеет только аналитическую форму и образуется с помощью личной формы глагола *быть* и инфинитива смыслового глагола.

Ваши же попытки образовать синтетическую форму имеют отношение только к глаголам совершенного вида. В данном случае можно рассмотреть глаголы "соблюсти" и "раздражить", образующие видовую пару с исходными.

Глагол **"раздражить"** имеет все нормативно образуемые личные формы (**Я раздражу, вы раздражите, мы раздражим**), но он сам по себе крайне редко употребляется, поэтому возникают трудности в использовании личных форм.

Глагол **"соблюсти"** вообще никаких при ограничений образовании личных форм не имеет: **соблюсти, соблюду, соблюдёшь; соблюл, соблюла, -ло, -ли/** 
Сомнения в этом можно объяснить разве что некоторой внешней схожестью личных форм с такими же у глаголов типа "победить", "(про)пылесосить", формы 1 лица для которых (победю, пылесошу) является просторечными или дискуссионными.

Comment: `как и у всех глаголов совершенного вида` - исправьте опечатку, **не**совершенного.

Comment: @tum_ спасибо . . .

Comment: Но эти формы же совсем не звучат. .Разве можно их употреблять?

Comment: @oleedd Можно. Употребляйте. Но в меру.